# joomla 2.5 and community builder 1.9

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-community-builder

I have an old installation of Joomla 2.5 and I use  community builder 1.9.
I have 2 languages at Joomla installation, Greek and English and I have a registration form at Greek that I want to have at English also.
As I notice there is the field management that allows only one language (The form use the title of the fields).
Can I use a second language for the registration form?

Answer (score 0):

You can now upgrade to **2.1.0 version**, which has all available in many languages.
Don't forget to download and install the Community Builder Greek translation as a separate Joomla module installation at
https://www.joomlapolis.com/downloads/languages